# Why does this header keep growing from page to page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm using a `tikz` picture as part of a header, with `scrlayer-scrpage` and `geometry`.

If I define the height with a fixed value, the header appears as intended. However, if I substitute `\headheight`, the header grows from page to page. Here's an illustration of the problem. The odd page contains the expanding header and the even page the fixed one:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=4cm,bindingoffset=1cm,
top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1.5cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myheader}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=\headheight,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,minimum height=\headheight,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,minimum height=\headheight,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\myheadertwo}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=1.5cm,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,minimum height=1.5cm,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,minimum height=1.5cm,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\lohead*{\myheader}
\lehead*{\myheadertwo}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the images below, on the first double-page spread, the headers are equal, but the odd-page header keeps growing.

Pages 1 and 2:
[image: Pages 1 and 2]

Pages 17 and 18:
[image: Pages 17 and 18]

For my actual document, I can easily use fixed values, so this isn't an immediate problem, but I'd like to understand the cause of this behavior in case there's some deeper underlying issue that could come back to bite me.

Comment: You can switch it off by adding `\newlength{\myheadheight}
\setlength{\myheadheight}{\headheight}` and using `\myheadheight` instead of `\headheight`.

Comment: Right, and effectively that's what I do in the full document. I'm just curious about _why_ it's behaving this way rather than how to work around it.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that TeX keeps adjusting this length. And this seems to be triggered by your command, but I guess that you know all that. And I have no idea why that is. The only "advantage" of the above comment is that you do not have to hard-code `1.5cm`.

Comment: I've stripped down the actual picture for the sake of the MWE. Suffice it to say that I need tikz for some more complicated things that aren't shown here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scrlayer-scrpages tells you why it happens. You only need to look in the log-file:

```
Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 83.4793pt needed,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 79.39928pt found.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \headheight, for further
(scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting geometry's option
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `head=83.4793pt'.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also decrease \topmargin on input line 47.
```

(I got this some days ago too and wished I could tell scrlayer not to bother and keep my layout as it is ...).

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive that asking for a picture of \headheight produces one that is larger than \headheight.

Comment: You are not asking for a picture of\headheight but for a node inside this picture.

Answer (score 1):

Your pictures are inserted above the baseline of the header. But `\headheight` is the total height of the header including a depth below the baseline. So you have to shift the pictures down by `\dp\strutbox` to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=4cm,bindingoffset=1cm,
top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1.5cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myheader}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={minimum height=\headheight}]
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\myheadertwo}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={minimum height=1.5cm}]
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\lohead*{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\myheader}}
\lehead*{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\myheadertwo}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=4cm,bindingoffset=1cm,
top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1.5cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myheader}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=\dp\strutbox,nodes={minimum height=\headheight}]
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\myheadertwo}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=\dp\strutbox,nodes={minimum height=1.5cm}]
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\lohead*{\myheader}
\lehead*{\myheadertwo}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

---

You could also decrease the height of the nodes by `-\dp\strutbox`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=4cm,bindingoffset=1cm,
top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1.5cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myheader}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={minimum height=\headheight-\dp\strutbox}]
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\myheadertwo}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={minimum height=1.5cm-\dp\strutbox}]
    \node (graybar) 
    [fill=black!30,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=west] {};
    \node (leftsidebar) at (graybar.west)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=west] {};
    \node (rightsidebar) at (graybar.east)
    [fill=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=12pt,anchor=east] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\lohead*{\myheader}
\lehead*{\myheadertwo}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

---

Or you use `\smash` inside `\lohead*` and `\lehead*` to hide the height of the pictures.